# ready event and filter conditions not working in JQXGrid

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jqxgrid

I have used jqx grid in my application. I want to apply filter conditions for a particular column in jqxgrid. I have finished the coding part of filter and added that filter function in ready event. The Problem is ready event not getting fired.Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
 function loadGrid(data, ref, undo) {
        try {
            var source =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields:
                [
                    { name: 'ProductionResource', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ItemStatus', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'FutureStatus', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'Abc1Code', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ItemNumber', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'FirmDemands', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'NetForecast', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'PromotionalLift', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'TotalReceipts', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'ItemQuantity', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'FirmProduction', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'PlannedProduction', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'RouterMultipleQuantity', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'WeekEnding', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'WeightedPriority', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'ItemSupplyDays', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'ShippableInventory', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'SafetyStock', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'KeyItem', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'DerivedForecastFactor', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'ConstraintUsage', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'TotalConstraintUsage', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'ProductionMinimum', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'ItemDescription', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'StatusChangeDate', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'OrdConstraint', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'HoldBuyCode', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'MakeBuyCode', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ForecastPlannerId', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'DailyForecast', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'ShipInvSafetyStock', type: 'number' },

                    //{ name: 'FriendlyDescription', type: 'string' },
                    //{ name: 'StatusChangeDate', type: 'string' },
                    //{ name: 'StatusCode', type: 'string' },
                    //{ name: 'MULQ', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'Inordermultiple', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'AdjProdQty', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'AdjInOutQty', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'NewATP', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'UNSW', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'UnconstrainedProdPlan', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'UnconSI', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'InconSISS', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'SISSQtypossibleremove', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'PossibleAdjQty', type: 'number' },
                    { name: 'ReasonCode', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'ShippableInv', type: 'number' }
                ],
                localdata: data
            };
var addfilter = function () {

    var filtergroup = new $.jqx.filter();

    var filter_or_operator = 1;
    var filtervalue = 'Beate';
    var filtercondition = 'contains';
    var filter1 = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, filtercondition);

    filtervalue = 'Andrew';
    filtercondition = 'contains';
    var filter2 = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, filtercondition);

    filtergroup.addfilter(filter_or_operator, filter1);
    filtergroup.addfilter(filter_or_operator, filter2);
    // add the filters.
    $("#mainData").jqxGrid('addfilter', 'Inordermultiple', filtergroup);
    // apply the filters.
    $("#mainData").jqxGrid('applyfilters');
}

           var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            $("#mainData").jqxGrid(
           {
               width: '99.5%',
               pageable: false,
               height: '100%',
               rowsheight: 30,
               altrows: true,
               source: dataAdapter,
               sortable: false,


               filterable: true,
               filtermode: 'excel',
               columnsresize: true,
               columnsreorder: true,
               editable: true,
               //selectionmode: 'multiplecellsadvanced',

               autoshowfiltericon: true,

                ready: function () {
                       addfilter();
               },
               //autoshowfiltericon: false,
               columns: [
                 { text: 'Production Resource', datafield: 'ProductionResource', width: '8.5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Item Status', datafield: 'ItemStatus', width: '8.5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Future Status', datafield: 'FutureStatus', width: '6%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'ABC 1 (Tiers)', datafield: 'Abc1Code', width: '5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Item #', datafield: 'ItemNumber', width: '8.5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Firm Demands', datafield: 'FirmDemands', width: '6%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Net Forecast', datafield: 'NetForecast', width: '6%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Promotional Lift Qty', datafield: 'PromotionalLift', width: '8%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Total Receipts', datafield: 'TotalReceipts', width: '6.5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'MSIORD Refresh', datafield: 'ItemQuantity', width: '8%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Firm Prod.', datafield: 'FirmProduction', width: '7%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Planned Prod.', datafield: 'PlannedProduction', width: '7.8%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Router Multiple Qty', datafield: 'RouterMultipleQuantity', width: '8%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'ATP (Week Ending)', datafield: 'WeekEnding', width: '6%', cellsformat: 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Weighted Priority', datafield: 'WeightedPriority', width: '7%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Days of Supply (Week ending Value)', datafield: 'ItemSupplyDays', width: '7%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Shippable Inv Qty', datafield: 'ShippableInventory', width: '8%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Safety Stock Qty', datafield: 'SafetyStock', width: '7%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Key Item', datafield: 'KeyItem', width: '4.5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Derived Fcst.Factor', datafield: 'DerivedForecastFactor', width: '9%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Constraint Usage', datafield: 'ConstraintUsage', width: '7.5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Total Constraint Usage', datafield: 'TotalConstraintUsage', width: '7.5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Minimum Production Order Qty / Production Min', datafield: 'ProductionMinimum', width: '8%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Item Description', datafield: 'ItemDescription', width: '5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Status Chg. Date', datafield: 'StatusChangeDate', width: '5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Constraint', datafield: 'OrdConstraint', type: 'string', width: '5%', hidden: true, editable: false },
                 { text: 'Hold/ Buy', datafield: 'HoldBuyCode', width: '6.5%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Make / Buy Code', datafield: 'MakeBuyCode', width: '7%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Fcst. Planner', datafield: 'ForecastPlannerId', width: '8%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Daily Forecast', datafield: 'DailyForecast', width: '8%', editable: false },
                 { text: 'Ship Inv – Safety Stock', datafield: 'ShipInvSafetyStock', width: '8%', editable: false },

                  //{ text: 'Friendly Description', datafield: 'FriendlyDescription', width: '7%' },
              //{ text: 'Status ChangeDate', datafield: 'StatusChangeDate', width: '8%' },
              //{ text: 'Status Code', datafield: 'StatusCode', width: '4%' },
              //{ text: 'MULQ', datafield: 'MULQ', width: '4%' },

              //{ text: 'Daily Fcst', datafield: 'DailyFcst', width: '5%' },
            { text: 'In order multiple', datafield: 'Inordermultiple', width: '5%', editable: false },
            { text: 'Adj Prod Qty', datafield: 'AdjProdQty', width: '5%', editable: true },
            { text: 'Adj In/Out Qty', datafield: 'AdjInOutQty', width: '5%', editable: false },
            { text: 'New ATP', datafield: 'NewATP', width: '5%', editable: false },
            { text: 'UN/SW', datafield: 'UNSW', width: '5%', editable: true },
            { text: 'Unconstrained Prod Plan', datafield: 'UnconstrainedProdPlan', width: '5%', editable: false },
            { text: 'Uncon SI', datafield: 'UnconSI', width: '5%', editable: false },
            { text: 'Uncon SI-SS', datafield: 'InconSISS', width: '5%', editable: false },
            { text: 'SI-SS Qty possible remove', datafield: 'SISSQtypossibleremove', width: '5%', editable: false },
            { text: 'Possible Adj Qty', datafield: 'PossibleAdjQty', width: '5%', editable: false },
            { text: 'Reason Code', datafield: 'ReasonCode', width: '5%', editable: false },
            { text: 'New Shippable Inventory', datafield: 'ShippableInv', width: '5%', editable: false },
               ],

           });




            $("#popupWindow").jqxWindow({
                width: 250, resizable: false, isModal: true, autoOpen: false, cancelButton: $("#Cancel"), modalOpacity: 0.01
            });

            $("#popupWindow").on('open', function () {
                //$("#reasoncode").jqxInput('selectAll');
            });

            $("#Cancel").jqxButton({ theme: 'energyblue' });
            $("#Save").jqxButton({ theme: 'energyblue' });

            // update the edited row's cell value when the user clicks the 'Save' button.
            $("#Save").click(function () {
                if (editrow >= 0) {
                    var row = { ReasonCode: $("#reasoncode").val() };
                    var rowID = $('#mainData').jqxGrid('getrowid', editrow);
                    $("#mainData").jqxGrid('setcellvalue', editrow, 'ReasonCode', $("#reasoncode").val());
                    $("#popupWindow").jqxWindow('hide');
                }
            });

            $("#mainData").on("columnclick", function (event) {
                var column = event.args.datafield;
                resizeColumn(column);
            });

            $("#mainData").on("cellclick", function (event) {
                if (event.args.datafield == "ReasonCode") {
                    //open the popup window when the user clicks a button.
                    editrow = event.args.rowindex;
                    var offset = $("#mainData").offset();
                    //$("#popupWindow").jqxWindow({ position: { x: parseInt(offset.left) + 60, y: parseInt(offset.top) + 60 } });
                    $("#popupWindow").jqxWindow({ position: { x: parseInt(offset.left) + 850, y: parseInt(offset.top) + 60 } });

                    // get the clicked row's data and initialize the input fields.
                    var dataRecord = $("#mainData").jqxGrid('getrowdata', editrow);
                    $("#reasoncode").val(dataRecord.ReasonCode);

                    // show the popup window.
                    $("#popupWindow").jqxWindow('open');
                }
            });

            EnableDisableRefUndos(data.length, ref, undo);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
        disableImage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ready is called just once i.e as far as I see in your code you assume that it will be called multiple times as it's placed within a function. My suggestion is to have 1 function which creates the Grid and another one which updates the data source related stuff like: $("#grid").jqxGrid({source: newAdapter}); when the data should be updated. It is also important to bind to events only once, not multiple times.